# Security implications of decrypting a PGP/GnuPG-encrypted file inside command substitution in bash

Tags: bash, security, encryption, gnupg

I use [aqbanking](https://www.aquamaniac.de/rdm/) to download my bank statements over HCBI. Normally, aqbanking will ask for the bank login credentials during download but you can also store these inside an unencrypted pinfile and pass the path to the pinfile to aqbanking on the command line.

I do not want to store the pinfile unencrypted on my hard disk. I use full-disk encryption but I am a bit paranoid about accidentally leaking the pinfile in an unencrypted backup.

My idea is to encrypt the pinfile using GnuPG and then decrypt the pinfile on-the-fly using process substitution in bash.

Instead of running:

```
aqbanking-cli -P /path/to/unencrypted-pin-file ...
```

I am running:

```
aqbanking-cli -P <(gpg -q --decrypt /path/to/encrypted/pinfile) ...
```

This works, however I am concerned about potential security implications.

My assumption is that the file is only decrypted in memory and its contents are accessed as a memory-mapped file. The unencrypted contents are never stored on disk. **Is that true?**

I am on macOS but on Linux I suspect that the output of the contents might be accessible for the root user using the `proc` filesystem. **Is that true?**

**What are other security implications of my approach?**

Note: I had originally asked [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519709/security-implications-of-decrypting-a-pgp-gnupg-encrypted-file-inside-command-su?stw=2) but it was closed there as off-topic it was suggested to post it here.